# Ionic View Manage Apps

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I uploaded a test app to Ionic (don't know the exact name for this) with the command `ionic upload` from the command line, and I can access them nicely with the Ionic View application I have installed on my iPhone.

However, I remember that they have a web interface for this too, but can't find the link for the life of me. I searched the [website](http://ionicframework.com/), went through my emails, googled, but nothing. I even found the same question on the [official forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-view-app-manage/15812) - sadly unanswered.

Comment: I was starting to think I was losing my mind. I knew I had seen this before, but no amount of Googling turned it up again.

Comment: @isherwood: exactly my case! I don't get it why the hid it so well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, sure enough, after going through my deleted emails I found a welcome email from Ionic stating that the login is at https://apps.ionic.io/login. Will reply to that official post too...

Comment: And how would I have logged in if I didn't know the actual apps.ionic.io?